# ZF2 get $_SESSION

Tags: session, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-session

I'm setting `$_SESSION` in a part of my application which is not routed by Zend. (`myhost.local/example.php` -> set `$_SESSION['user']`)

Now I want to access the `$_SESSION['user']` in my Zend application.
(`myhost.local/newgeniuszend/index` -> cant get the `$_SESSION['user']`)

What can I do?

Comment: For the idiots like me:
Dont forget session_start();

:D

Answer (score 3):

In Zend Framework you should **not** interact with the php `$_SESSION` global directly. Instead you should use the session tools that are shipped with ZF2 in [the `zend-session` module](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-session). For session management there is a so called session-manager (`Zend\Session\SessionManager`).

Refer to the [official ZF2 documentation here](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.session.manager.html).

There are a lot of questions and answers about how to handle sessions in Zend Framework 2 on stackoverflow. If you search [through those posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=session%20%5Bzend-framework2%5D) you probably will get answers to all your questions related to this topic.